Elevation angle of LEO satellite as a function of time
Let a point on Earth be denoted with (lon,lat,altitude).
Let a LEO satellite be defined by its altitude and inclination.
I would like to compute the angular speed and elevation as a function of time.
With the 3rd law of Kepler I can estimate an average speed.
How to derive the elevation ?

What have you tried? How far have you gotten with this? Homework-like questions are not appreciated on this site.

I read this document https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/13/7/4405
which mentions in equation (1) the elevation angle as a function of the longitude of the satellite. But I don't know how it was derived first. I don't understand where it comes from. Then, to derive the elevation as a function of time, I need its longitude as a function of time. If I assume a speed v (Kepler), the longitude is expressed as a function of the inclination and the speed ?
